# On marriage within groups of the same caste

Tags: caste-system, marriage, dharma-shastras, tradition, brahmins

Kulinism was a practice unique to the Bengali Hindu society. Hagiographical accounts & extensive genealogical texts like *Kūlapañjikā*s state that this system was introduced by a semi-legendary Bengali Hindu king named Ādiśūra while some attribute it to Vallālasena (1160-79) with the aim of rejuvenating Hinduism following  the end of the Buddhist Pālas in Bengal. In this system Bengali Brahmins were classified into 2 groups-*kulīna* & *śrotriya*. *Kulīna* Brahmins were the descendents of 5 Brahmins invited to settle in Bengal by the King from Kannauj while *Srotriya* Brahmins were descendents of pre-existing Brahmins. Ādiśura/Vallālasena declared the *kulīna*s to be superior to the *śrotriya*s & forbade *pratiloma* marriage between them, which resulted in situations like a *kulīna* girl being married off to a *kulīna* groom whose age is equal to that of her grandfather due to lack of other suitable *kulīna* match nearby (since it was considered sinful for a man to keep his daughter unmarried after the age of 12) & a *kulīna* man marrying *en-masse* *kulīna* girls far beyond his capacity to maintain & provide for, resulting in married *kulīna* girls remaining in their paternal household for their entire lives & raising their children without any  support from her husband. The *Vaidya*s & *Kāyastha*s (traditionally regarded as only below Brahmins in Bengali Hindu hierarchy) also adopted this system of kulinism mimicking the Brahmins. Kulinism died out due to bans on polygamy & child marriage & influence of Communist rule.

My question is whether there is any scriptural injuction for banning *pratiloma* marriage between 2 groups **belonging to the same caste** ?